# Why is debug logging SOAP Requests with Axis2 1.8 not working ANYMORE?

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am currently working to upgrade a relatively old application to utilize Axis2 - the current version 1.8.2 as a SOAP Client (formerly using AXis2 1.3)
When there was a need to analyze the generated SOAP request (and response), it was easy:
I added the following VM Arguments to the run configuration (or as startup parameters on a test environment)
Apache Tomcat 8.5

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=debug
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=debug
```

...and perfect and complete the xml structures appeared in the console log and/or logfile.

eg.:
2023/03/10 08:27:22:518 CET [DEBUG] header - ->> "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2023/03/10 08:27:22:518 CET [DEBUG] header - ->> "SOAPAction: "http://www.host.com/servicece-3.0/startProcessInstance"[\r][\n]"
2023/03/10 08:27:22:518 CET [DEBUG] header - ->> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
2023/03/10 08:27:22:518 CET [DEBUG] header - ->> "Host: host.at:9085[\r][\n]"
2023/03/10 08:27:22:518 CET [DEBUG] header - ->> "Content-Length: 3732[\r][\n]"
2023/03/10 08:27:22:518 CET [DEBUG] header - ->> "[\r][\n]"
2023/03/10 08:27:22:519 CET [DEBUG] content - ->> "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soapenv:Header<ns49:ServiceContext xmlns:ns49="http://www.example.com/jp/ServiceLayerTypes-1.4" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"> [...]
2023/03/10 08:27:22:519 CET [DEBUG] EntityEnclosingMethod - -Request body sent

With Axi2 1.8.2 - nothing! I search configuration files for options, i read documentation on Axis2, Tomcat, searched forums...
Does anyone know about this? Experienced a similar problem? Any ideas?
Thnx

I tried the same configuration as with Axis2 1.3 and 1.8.2 - i expect the same debug output.

Answer (score 0):

In the last versions of Apache Axis2, at least starting from version 18.x, you can log the request and the response by simply setting the `debug` level to `org.apache.http`.